# Why does running "Jupyter notebook"command in Anaconda prompt gives attribute error?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

This must really simple.

Running jupyter notebook in the Anaconda prompt gives me an attribute error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\anaconda\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 6, in <module>
    from notebook.notebookapp import main
  File "D:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 80, in <module>
    from .services.contents.manager import ContentsManager
  File "D:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\contents\manager.py", line 17, in <module>
    from nbformat import sign, validate as validate_nb, ValidationError
  File "D:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\nbformat\__init__.py", line 32, in <module>
    from .validator import validate, ValidationError
  File "D:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\nbformat\validator.py", line 12, in <module>
    from jsonschema import ValidationError
  File "D:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\jsonschema\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from jsonschema.exceptions import (
  File "D:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\jsonschema\exceptions.py", line 152, in <module>
    @attr.s(hash=True)
AttributeError: module 'attr' has no attribute 's'
```

thanks a lot for helping out.

Comment: Can you share some information about your environment?

Answer (score 1):

This issue got resolved. I did

pip uinstall attr
 pip install attrs

My Speculation 
This worked. Running the notebook probably required attrs module which maybe had the s attribute. Not sure though.